# Redirect to the origin url when login/logout is success disqus on android

Tags: android, url, webview, webkit, disqus

I have this problem how to intergrate Disqus into android native app.

After the login/logout request is successful disqus stays where it is. I.E. on a blank page

Now how to redirect the activity to load the origin url is the issue.

I have tried using the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`.  It seems that it doesn't listen to the inner iframe requests anyone with a hack. And what is the use of Contains() equals() etc etc methods of `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`? Here is my codes

```
String shortname = "https://disqus.com/next/login/?forum=rasimu.disqus.com" ;
String loginsuccess = "disqus.com/_ax/[twitter, google, facebook]/complete" ;
String loginsucess2 ="disqus.com/next/login-success/" ;@Override

public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
  webViewPreviousState = PAGE_REDIRECTED ;
  Log.v("TEST", url) ;
  if(url.equals(shortname) || url.equals(loginsuccess)|| url.equals(loginsucess2) )
    {
      view.loadUrl(uri);
    }
  else 
    {
      view.loadUrl(url);
    }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you found this but this blog entry might be useful for others with the same issue globeotter.com/blog/disqus-login-and-logout

Comment: Thanks ndgreen I saw it too i was about to answer my own question, they are cool in that blog cause i have searched for this thing for days. The problem is solved